# Как подключить в WP Bootstrap/свои стили, чтобы они имели наивысший приоритет?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

```
function my_assets() {
wp_register_style( 'bootstrap-css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/bootstrap.min.css', array('fusion-dynamic-css') );
wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap-css');
wp_enqueue_script('bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/bootstrap.min.js',array('jquery'),'3.3.7',true);
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_assets' );
```

bootstrap.min.js - подключается в футере, но не там, где я хочу.
bootstrap.min.css - подключаются вроде последними, но перетираются стилями, которые выше:(
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А `fusion-styles` как вы подключаете? Если он имеет отношение к теме - почему он в uploads?

Comment: подгрузился когда я стандартный контент в тему импортировал

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Есть вариант добавить !important к стилю, который хотите применить. Пример:

```
h1 {font-size:33px !important;}
```

У вас так происходит из за веса селекторо 
.fusion-modal h1 > h1, где бы вы не размещали подключение. Помимо !important(считается не хорошей практикой, так как его ничем не перебить), можете вес селектора увеличить. Например div.fusion-modal h1.

Comment: Почитал про приоритет в стилях. Вы правы, действительно вес больше. Но использовать !important всюду я просто запарюсь))) Я лутше возьму другую тему, где не будет такой проблемы. А вам спасибо за ответ и хорошего дня!

Comment: Ну тогда перепишите селектор)

Comment: Боюсь, что много очень переписывать прийдется. Лутше зделаю в другой теме.

Comment: Попробуйте добавить стили, что  вам нужны в head - это тоже повысит приоритет.

Comment: Поставьте галочку слева пожалуйста!)

Comment: Ааа, вы про чат, я думал возле селектора))))))))

Answer (score 0):

> bootstrap.min.css - подключаются вроде последними, но перетираются
>   стилями, которые выше

В общем и целом вам нужно прочитать одну единственную статью: [Каскадирование](http://htmlbook.ru/samcss/kaskadirovanie). Если совсем коротко, то есть три момента, на которые смотрят браузеры при принятии решения о том, какой конкретно стиль применить к тому или иному элементу: вес того или иного стиля как такового (стиль автора, стиль браузера и тд), порядок подключения стилей в html-файле и специфичность (это термин) селекторов или их сочетания. Обо всем этом есть по ссылке.

Если же отвечать конкретно на ваш вопрос, то обратите внимание на указанные вами на скриншоте места в коде - в одном случае написано правило просто для `h1, .h1`, а в другом случае - для .fusion-modal h1, и в последнем варианте специфичность выходит больше. Как выйти из этой ситуации, решать только вам. Можно править файлы стилей, можно попробовать объединить их. Главное понимать, что в итоге решать, что будет в итоге применено, будет не ваш код, а браузер, на основании своих правил.

> bootstrap.min.js - подключается в футере, но не там, где я хочу

Здесь могу только посоветовать почитать документацию к WP о функциях, которыми вы подключаете этот файл.

Comment: Ясно. Спасибо за ответ. Самый простой вариант для меня - поменять тему. А вам хорошего дня!